# Which EQ is suitable? Alloy 2, Pro-Q, or other?

Tags: izotope, eq, transients, equalization

I'm looking into getting an EQ for $200 or less, preferably less. Alloy 2 retails for $150. Pro-Q is a little more expensive, but around the same price.

I like Alloy because of its multi-band transient enhancer. I already have Transient Master from Native Instruments, but it's not multi-band, and that would be convenient for drum tracks.

I really like Pro-Q, and I particularly like the ability to throw on an instant bandpass filter to hear just a section. If Alloy 2 could do that, I'd definitely go for Alloy 2. I have seen no example of Alloy 2 being able to do that.

There may be a less expensive, very flexible EQ that I don't know about.

I'm assuming they're very similar in terms of sound quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alloy 2 is kind of a one stop shop and really awesome in my opinion. I'm considering buying it myself. I love the pro q, but personally was looking for a channel strip type of plug, and alloy really does that well.

Comment: I would concur with Alloy 2, but my main exposure with Izotope is through Ozone mastering, which is similar. I would agree that Alloy 2 is more of a channel strip than a dedicated EQ, but simply based on that principle I would go with Alloy; just like Dave, its on my purchase list.

@Jamil I think what you need to weigh up is what purpose you need the EQ for. If you are focusing on accurate EQ for filtering unwanted frequency transients, then a good parametric EQ or multiband compressor would suffice, but I am unsure what specific tasks you are needing it for other than some sound exploration

Answer (score 1):

I tend to avoid multi-band compressors.  Why should an instrument have different tone settings because it got louder in the mix?  They always seem to change the EQ in an unpredictable way.  That being said; are the two you mentioned expensive for just an EQ?  Maybe not to pros; but with Alloy, you also get a number of extras.  Which sounds better?  Both have demos.  I'd suggest listening both on program material you'd like to use it for, and listen very critically.  Try different instruments too, and different plugins on the same material with the same settings; to A/B them.  I've liked Ozone for quite some time pretty well; but for its harmonic exiciter - a very difficult thing to get right, but they do very well.  The Alloy 2 EQ has more features than the Ozone one.  EQ's I like right now: the SPL passive EQ's (I'm still trying to decide how much I like them) and the Sonnox Oxford EQ isn't very flexible, but it clearly won a shootout between several I conducted some time ago.  Another very strong contender: Uniquelizer.  It has several types of EQ for each band, practically unlimited bands, and a unique harmonic EQ, which takes out not only a notch, but also that notch at higher octaves - useful for getting out line hum reportedly.  Finally, SSL has an interesting parallel EQ concept.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that an equalizer is not worth much these days.

However:

MeldaProduction MAutoDynamicEQ
http://www.meldaproduction.com/plugins/product.php?id=MAutoDynamicEq

Answer (score 0):

DMG Audio Equilibrium.

The creators devoted their lifes to eqs and they certainly now what they are doing. The gui is fully configurable to personal preference + it sounds great. This plugin is really more than we'll ever need.